# How to find the rows with maximum number of variables columnwise r

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has thousands of rows and 25 columns. The rows have different lengths, meaning that not all have values for all columns. However, the empty cells are always at the end of the row:

```
1  1  1  1
1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1
```

How can I find the longest row? In the example above it would be row number 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the missing values are NAs and all those values are at the end.

```
 indx <- which.max(rowSums(!is.na(df1)))
```

Or we can use `apply` to loop over the rows

```
 indx <- which.max(apply(df1, 1, function(x) length(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

If the missing values are `''`

```
 indx <- which.max(apply(df1, 1, function(x) length(x[x!=''])))
```